# Kotlin: How can a child constructor use its parent's secondary constructor?

Tags: inheritance, constructor, kotlin

For example, we have this parent:

```
open class Parent(val id: Int, val name: String?) {
    constructor() : this(-1, null)
}
```

And a child, which must have both a two-param constructor and an empty constructor, like the parent:

```
class Child(id: Int, name: String?) : Parent(id, name) {
    constructor() : super() // syntax error
}
```

How can a child constructor use its parent's secondary constructor?

I am aware that I can implement a child constructor passing in the same values as the parent, but this not only seems redundant but also often times my childs have extra parameters for its primary constructor, but don't require intermediary constructors (constructors with params that don't include all the extra params). Here's an example child implementing it that way, in case I wasn't clear:

```
class Child(id: Int, name: String?) : Parent(id, name) {
    constructor() : this(-1, null) // no syntax error, but redundant
}
```

Comment: Please add the error message you are getting

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is imho using *default parameters* for your constructor

```
class Child(id: Int = -1, name: String? = null) : Parent(id, name)
```

Depending on how much influence you've got on the `Parent` class, maybe even

```
class Parent(val id: Int = -1, val name: String? = null)
```

This has one "drawback", though: you'll technically get three different constructors. But I can't see how this could be a problem, since you have to handle the `id=-1` and `name=null` cases anyway.

Additionally, I don't think your solution

```
class Child(id: Int, name: String?) : Parent(id, name) {
    constructor() : this(-1, null) 
}
```

is bad, or "redundant" in any way - on the contrary: it's highly expressive and explicit, so the reader knows exactly what your intention was.

Answer (score 11):

First, you can't extends the `Parent` class since it is not `open`ed.

Secondly, if a class has declared a primary constructor, you can't call the constructor of the superclass via `super` keyword.

On the other hand, if you want to call the superlcass's constructor by the keyword `super`. you need make the primary constructor to the secondary constructor, for example:

```
class Child : Parent {
  constructor(id: Int, name: String?) : super(id, name)
  constructor() : super()
}
```

Another option is let the secondary constructor call the primary constructor by `this` keyword, but I think it is unnecessary and duplicated parameters with superclass's secondary constructor:

```
class Child(id: Int, name: String?) : Parent(id, name) {
  constructor() : this(-1, null);
}
```