# Is there a way to inherit constructors in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, constructor

I have a `Parent` class which is extended by a lot of childs and I want to avoid to copy the long constructor in each of them because it is always the same.

```
open class Parent(arg1: Any, arg2: Any, arg3: Any...)

class ChildA(arg1: Any, arg2: Any, arg3: Any...): Parent(arg1, arg2, arg3...)
class ChildB(arg1: Any, arg2: Any, arg3: Any...): Parent(arg1, arg2, arg3...)
[...]
```

Is there a way to inherit the constructor or maybe a function implemented on the `Parent` that instantiates a `Child` class?

## Edit

My expectation is to implement the `Child` classes without having to define its constructor. The reason is that I have about 15 childs and each parameter have an optional value, so the resulting code is not so pretty.

Comment: Have u checked this https://stackoverflow.com/q/44772936/7666442

Comment: You can use **Design Builder Pattern** for such scenario where you're having too many parameters.

Comment: what is your expectation?

Comment: "maybe a function implemented on the Parent that instantiates a Child class" and "I have about 15 childs and each parameter have an optional value" sound like a bad design. It sounds like you want to implements some logic which, depending on parameter values, will select which class to instantiate. This is usually done using the factory pattern. But I suggest stepping back and trying to figure out if this approach may be trying to be too generic: Should *one* method be able to create instances of quite different classes? What are the actual relations between parameter values and child class?

Comment: @JimmyB My final objective is to implement a callback system. The parent class is a `GenericCallback<T>` and the childs are implementations of it (i.e `IntCallback: GenericCallback<Int>`). I think it is a good solution because each implementation needs specific code to "know" how to cast the callback result to `T` (for this reason, I need 15 implementations). And to answer your question, parameters needs information about `T`.

Comment: "I think it is a good solution because each implementation needs specific code" - I'm not (yet;-) questioning the inheritance you use. But in most cases generic/dynamic *instantiation* is not a good solution. Can you tell us what the logic should look like that decides which class to instantiate?

Comment: I have a list of functions that accepts just one subptype of this class. For example `foo(callback: IntCallback)`. Then, calling the dynamic instantation will call the constructor of `IntCallback`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's always the same (or only extended), you can create a class for holding the parameters:

```
data class ConstructorParams(arg1: Any, arg2: Any, arg3: Any...)

open class Parent(params: ConstructorParams)

class ChildA(params: ConstructorParams) : Parent(params)

class ChildB(params: ConstructorParams, extraParam: Int) : Parent(params)
```

You could add to it a helper function to avoid explicit `ConstructorParams` when instantiating the classes, but it has a performance trade-off (though this version won't work for `Child2`):

```
inline fun <reified T : Parent> create(arg1: Any, arg2: Any, arg3: Any...) = 
    T::class.primaryConstructor.call(ConstructorParams(arg1, arg2, ...))

create<Parent>(1, 2, "")
```